# Name file using first few words from file

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def save():
   summary = (text.get('1.0', '15.0')).rstrip()
   data = text.get('1.0', END)
   file = open(r"C:\Notes\"+summary+".txt", 'w')
   file.write(data)
   file.close()
```

Hello! I am trying to create a Notes using tkinter. I want to make a function that works "secretly" (I do not want to use `asksaveasfile` etc.) So what does it mean "secretly": User click save and see for example only: "File saved", but file must use first few words of a text as name. Intuitive, i see this like code above, but this does not work properly.

P.S. I need this path `"C:\Notes\..."`, can not do like `open(summary,'w').`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
file = open(f"C:/Notes/{summary}.txt", w)
```

Every Windows API accepts either forward or backward slashes, and this avoids the confusion of the `\"` you currently have.

Note, however, that users will be surprised by this.  How will they remember how the file was saved?  And what happens if two notes start with the same few words?  Notes from project calls often start with the name of the project every time.

Comment: I am going to show users where is folder with their files, but i would prefer manage them in application, so I would try to make something like a add_cascade list of them. Actually, also have question how can i show the name of files in list?

Comment: Well, that's a separate question.  I presume you know how to get the contents of a directory (`os.listdir`) or to walk a directory tree (`os.walk`).  Displaying that list depends on your app.

Comment: Thank you. And if i may: can i make unique file except using name? For example using date, but hide it someway. (I saw this idea: naming file using first few, on iphone's notes)